# String.split("*") returns Exception

Tags: java, android

String.split("*") return Exception in Android Eclipse

Is there Any solution...

Comment: If you have any exceptions thrown, you should post the logcat and the chunk of code where this happens.

Comment: * is not a valid regular expression

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: some would say read the javadoc of String.split...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String#split("*")` **should** throw an exception. [`String#split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a regular expression string, and `"*"` is an invalid regular expression. The `*` means "zero or more of the previous item" but there is no previous item.

If you're trying to split literally on asterisks, use: `split("\\*")`. There are two backslashes because you need to pass a backslash to the regular expression parser to tell it that the `*` is literal, and of course this is in a string, so to get a backslash, you have to escape it. Hence, two.

```
String[] splitOnAsterisk = "one*two*three".split("\\*");
```

Comment: Huh? `String.split accepts a regular expression string, and "*" is an regular expression.`

Comment: @The Elite: There was an important missing word there: "invalid" :) I've added it. (And thanks also to Christ Jester-Young who also tried to fix it for me, but in a different way.)

Answer (score 4):

completely guessing here, but have you tried escaping the `*`? i.e `String.split("\*")`? Also what are you trying to split on?

Comment: I imagine you'd need to double up the backslash, otherwise Java will try to interpret it as an escaped character within the string, rather than as an escape in the pattern.

Comment: I am trying this String containing * i.e. "C:/Abc*D:/def"

Comment: This is probably right, as I think `String.split` takes a String parameter that it uses as a regular expression, so `String.split("*")` is telling it to split on _everything_.

Comment: You need to write `"\\*"` because of string escaping in Java. Also, consider `String.split(Pattern.quote("*"))`.

Comment: A `*` by itself isn't even a valid regular expression, hence the exception. Splitting on everything would be `.*`

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead

```
String[] s1 = s.split("\\*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
String.split("[*]")
```

the split function takes a regex expression